# Asking if certain tools contain certain features?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, scope

I am doing a research on monetization tools for Android and mobile in general.

Would be appropriate to ask on Stack Overflow which monetization tools offer me certain features? I am not talking about the eCPM and such. I am talking about their SDKs and what kind of features are being offered from the various services out there.

Comment: Are you asking about specific features? Are you asking if they _exist_ or _how_ they work?

Comment: And you're sure the documentation doesn't provide the answer for you? I would hate for RTFM to be the actual answer to your questions.

Comment: @Bart A lot of questions in SO can be solved by RTFM or RTFC or reading the spec. One of the benefits of StackOverflow is that you can easily get the answer when searching for the problem. More than that, it's not only beneficial to developers, but it's beneficial to the site as well generating traffic.

Comment: First of all yes, I am asking if they exist! Because I am imagining something that probably no one has implemented. The basic idea is for me the developer to pass parameters and affect which ads should appear most and which less. Anyway I didn't want to write this in a comment but actually my question is no longer than that. I hope I was clear enough :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum only ever if that information is not easy to glance from the documentation. SO is trying to be a repository of knowledge related to programming problems. Not a substitute for actually reading the documentation. It should at most [cover the gap between documentation and practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170297/stack-overflow-in-the-news-effects-on-documentation).

Comment: @Bart I think maybe I phrased myself poorly. I'm not saying it should _replace_ the documentation. However, covering issues that _can_ be solved by reading the documentation is another thing. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340673/) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124884/)  [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724255) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089284/) of questions that could be solved by reading the manual or the specification. Still, it seems like these are all useful to the community. I hope this clarifies what I meant.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Okay, that's what I would see as "covering the gap" indeed. I have a sneaking suspicion however that the OP's questions would move into "not constructive" of "NARQ" territory. So perhaps some examples would help there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think they're on topic.

It sounds like you're asking how to solve a specific programming issue (doing what the feature offers in Android). I think a lot of programmers would be interested in reading such questions and answers.

While often these sort of questions are not the most interesting ones or the most high quality ones in StackOverflow, they are one of the most useful types of question.

As a developer, when starting with a new technology often I run into these sort of questions and they've helped me in the past.

Some positive examples:

- [Does Java support default parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values)
- [Does Android support near real time push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243066/does-android-support-near-real-time-push-notification)
- [Does Internet Explorer support pushState and replaceState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722815/does-internet-explorer-support-pushstate-and-replacestate)
- [Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)
- [Does IE9 support console.log, and is it a real function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function)
- [Can prettify.js be extended to support Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957682/can-prettify-js-be-extended-to-support-mathematica)

You can even notice that such a question *you* asked was accepted by the community as constructive:

- [Android <-> iOS direct communication (Bluetooth). Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580096/android-ios-direct-communication-bluetooth-is-it-possible)

As you can see in [search for possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3apossible) there are quite a few such questions that were useful to StackOverflow.